# AJAX How to use key:value

Tags: php, ajax

My form:

```
<form action="html_post.php" method="post" id="myform">

    <textarea id="textarea" placeholder="Add your comment" name="posting"> </textarea>

    <input class="button" type="button" name="send" value="Send">
</form>
```

I have such code

```
$(".button").click(function () {

    var content = $("#myform").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: "add_post.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            text: content,
            action: "add_post"
        },
        success: function () {
            $('#comment_block').load('list_post.php');
            document.getElementById('textarea').value = "";
        }
    })

});
```

And such php:

```
echo mysqli_error($connection);
if (strlen($_POST['posting']) >= 5) {
    $text = htmlspecialchars($_POST['posting']);
    $insert = "INSERT INTO post(content) VALUE ('$text')";
    mysqli_query($connection, $insert);
}
```

But it does not add text to db. I'm just learning ajax and it's my first experience with key:value so can you help me?

And yep, there is no shown errors

Comment: where should `$_POST['posting']` come from? Is this an input in your form?

Comment: What's the output of `mysqli_error()`?

Comment: In addition: what says error log (php / or server)?

Comment: I bet for an undefined Index 'posting'

Comment: @Jeff I add to the question

Comment: Why are you using `htmlspecialchars()`? That's not for escaping SQL literals, it's for displaying literal data on a web page.

Comment: you should better use `.serializeArray()` then you'll have 'posting' as an key/value inside `$_POST['text']`

Comment: You should use a prepared statement instead of substituting a variable into the query.

Comment: @Barmar ok, as I've read the docs serialize returns a string, serializeArray an array. - didn't know, that both would work the same in this case.

Comment: @Jeff Good point, although that still won't allow him to access it the way he wants, because it's not an associative array.

Comment: @Біпач I don't know why you went and changed `VALUES` to `VALUE` https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47984344/6. It's perfectly valid in MySQL https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html - You might have taken that from one of the answers, which is incorrect. I have rolled the question back to a previous revision. Edit: That answer has now been deleted https://stackoverflow.com/a/47984460/

Comment: `echo mysqli_error($connection);` should go under `mysqli_query($connection, $insert);` and with another conditional. Use error reporting and look at your developer console. You are running this off a webserver right? and not has `file:///`.

Answer (score 1):

The way you've written it, there is no `$_POST['posting']`. Instead, `$_POST['text']` contains a URL-encoded string containing all the inputs in the form, i.e. a string like `"posting=blah blah blah"`.

What you probably want is:

```
$(".button").click(function () {

    var content = $("#myform").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: "add_post.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: content + '&action=add_post',
        success: function () {
            $('#comment_block').load('list_post.php');
            document.getElementById('textarea').value = "";
        }
    })

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your posted code, on the server there will be two keys set in the $_POST variable. These are the ones that you define at your ajax request in javascript: `text` and `action`.

So while you check `$_POST['posting']` it does not exists, but there are `$_POST['text']` and `$_POST['action']`. `$_POST['text']` will contain all the form fields as an URL-encoded string, like `"posting=xyz"`. In order to access these values, you could use the [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) php function that parses this string as it were a query string.

So the condition at the server side could be something like as follows.

```
if (isset($_POST['text'])) {
    // $formdata passed in by reference, it will contain all the form fields
    parse_str($_POST['text'], $formdata);
}

if (isset($formdata['posting']) && strlen($formdata['posting']) >= 5) {
    // Perform db operation
}
```

Comment: What he probably should have done is `content = $("#textarea").val()`.

Comment: @Barmar Where exactly? The problem is that he is checking the wrong keys on $_POST.

Comment: `$_POST['text']['posting']` won't work, because `contents` is a string, not an array.